# Error "identifier "KERN_INFO" is undefined" in kernel module

Tags: ubuntu, module, kernel

I am tring to run a kernel module. I am getting an error in the `printk` function- that "KERN_INFO" is undefined. I am running the program in ubuntu. Here are the function:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
```

Comment: Do not describe the error message ("that "KERN_INFO" is undefined"). Instead, show (add to the question post) it **exactly** as it is.